# toggle element visibility in ember js based on a boolean

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have created template and controller both called navbar. The code that i have in controller is simply

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    isLogged: true,
});
```

and that in template is

```
    {{#if isLogged}}
        {{#link-to 'login' class="uk-button uk-button-danger"}}Login{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to 'signup' class="uk-button uk-button-danger"}}Join now{{/link-to}}
    {{else}}
        {{#link-to 'dashboard' class="uk-button uk-button-danger"}}Dashboard{{/link-to}}
    {{/if}}
<button class="uk-button uk-button-large uk-button-primary uk-width-1-1" disabled={{isLogged}}>Test button</button>
```

The same does not seem to be working. Am i going wrong somewhere ?

The template and controller were generated using ember generator itself and the code above is the only modifications that i made.

EDIT:

Exploring the documentation, i noticed that the name of controller should be same as defined in route. Now navbar is only a template which i import using `partial` is there any workaround i might use for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a component for this.

Use `{{partial}}` only if you want to render a template in the current context. Use it only if your `.hbs` files became to big, but use it rarely. Often a component is the better choice.

Also there you should almost never use `{{render}}`. You can almost always refactor it to a component.

Also using [`{{render}}` with a model param is deprecated.](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_model-param-in-code-render-code-helper)

Comment: thanks for the tip. newbie here so took me some time to get through the docs. Sorry can't upvote the answer limited reputation :(

Comment: I'm glad I could help. But consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answers, you don't need up vote privilege for that.

Comment: did that . Thanks again for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that 'partial' will only provide the template not the controllers. The correct way for this would be to use `render` which will import views and controllers also.